# Find Master Page Dropdown control on other Master Page ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have two master page one is `User.Master` and Other is `Account.Master`
I want to find `DropDown control` selected value from `User.Master` on master page `Account.Master` Page .

Is that possible to get one master control on second master page in the same application?

Please give me suggestion and help me.

Comment: try to use `Session`

Comment: they are not nested master page

Comment: it is better to use session for passing values between pages.store your value like this    **Session["key"]=your_Value;**

Comment: Can you show us the code and general mechanics you've used to incorporate two master pages on the same web page, please?

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with Classic ASP - can you edit your question and remove the tag, please?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nested master pages you can do it, you cannot access one master page from another. Page can use one master page at a time.

Comment: i am not using nested master pages

Comment: in such case better practice is to store value in Session

Comment: This isn't really an answer - it's a comment.